# Using I2C on XMC1100 2Go

Tags: c, i2c, infineon

I recently got the [Infineon 3D Magnetic Sensor 2Go development board (based on the XMC1100 microcontroller)](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/sensor/magnetic-position-sensor/3d-magnetic-sensor/tle493d-a2b6-ms2go/) and I would like to know **how to read input from the 3D Magnetic Sensor** which is interfaced through **I2C**. I am new to the Infineon development system, so I do not know how to gather and process input from the sensor.

Here is what I know so far:

- The main microcontroller is an Infineon **XMC1100-Q024F0064**
- The 3D Magnetic Sensor is connected to the XMC1100 via **I2C**
- How to **program and control the GPIO** on the XMC1100
- How to use the supplied stand-alone applet to view data from the Sensor

I have the **DAVE IDE**, the **APPs** extension, and I am **writing my code in C**. I **need to use DAVE** to accomplish my desired end result, but I would be interested to know the Arduino method as well.

Thank you in advance for your help!